# -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hfyyLsK \dump"

Tags: errors

What are these commands? and what do they do? I am using TexStudio. These aren't affecting the output of my pdfs but since I have seen them I had experienced that some processes have greater ids on the taskmanager and also when I use the ps command on powershell.

```
Error: Could not start the command: - -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hbAZRYG \dump"

Error: Could not start the command: -

Error: Could not start the command: - -interaction=nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hfyyLsK \dump"

Error: Could not start the command: -
```

Many thanks

Comment: "nonstopmode" is intended to tell tex not to stop a run, even if there are errors.  -ini" is intended to use the "initex" form of the engine to prepare a "format file" which contains everything that is newly defined so that this can all be preloaded the next time tex is run with it included; the idea is to save time in subsequent runs.  and "dump" tells tex to actually write out the format file for future use.  why this didn't work, I'm unable to say.

Comment: you appear to be missing the command, presumably a misconfiguration in your editor or build script. What you show are the _arguments_ to `pdflatex` without the call to pdflatex. You intended to run `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode` and you are running `-interaction=nonstopmode`so getting an error from the operating system.